# How to Create SharePoint Environment for group of companies with separate Active Directories

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement where my company CEO bought three more companies and now became 4 companies. Every company has its own Active Directory and they are on different locations within a city. How would I use different AD's for SharePoint? What kinda network do we need to bring so all companies can access SharePoint from there locations? etc

Got a requirement to implement SharePoint so all companies can work in collaborative manner and get alerts using email as well. Can anyone let me know what needs to be done in a proper sequence manner.

1?
2?
3?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you looking to implement an on premise installation or SharePoint Online instance? It can be accomplished in both, although I would say a lot easier to do in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Hi Rick..looking for On-Premises solution. My companies has reservations to keep confidential data on cloud as its a pharma company so regulatory documentation is sensitive in nature.

Comment: Ok, it's a little trickier to do on-Premise but not impossible. I am guessing there is no trust between any of these domains? There all in separate active directory at separate sites?

Comment: yes totally separate rick.